# Getting error log for every URL hits in magento1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, error, url, log, varien

I am getting this error log for any url hit in my magento..What could be the reason and how to solve this?

```
2014-11-14T07:49:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /var/www/beta_dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 94
2014-11-14T07:49:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /var/www/beta_dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 95
2014-11-14T07:49:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /var/www/beta_dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
2014-11-14T07:49:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /var/www/beta_dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 97
2014-11-14T07:49:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /var/www/beta_dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98
2014-11-14T07:49:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /var/www/beta_dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 99
2014-11-14T07:49:47+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /var/www/beta_dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 108
2014-11-14T07:49:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/beta_dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 108
```

Comment: Do you have developer mode enabled? (`SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"` in `.htaccess`).

Comment: @jonathan_hussey If he was running developer mode, the first notice would be fatal. Notices are always logged to system log if the logging is enabled. In fact, turning on developer mode would be a good idea to track down why this variable is not set in one of the deeper parts of the core.

Comment: @Jonathan Hussey No,i didn't set that.

Comment: @Melvyn I know that, I was asking for the reason you also conclude - do we have a call stack to go on.  The error posted does not *neccessarily* give any indication as to the origin of the problem. Manik can you set that then and post the call stack you will see on the frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess you have edited your core, as that variable is defined.

See https://github.com/sonassi/magento-ce/blob/1.7.0.0/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php#L86

Restore a clean, unmodified copy of the core.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ..That file responsible for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution..

```
    // session cookie params
    /*$cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );*/
```

This makes the problem.so after uncomment this variable ,my problem solved..

```
    // session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to mod core file!!!!

Try these settings in : System > Config > Web

Cookie Lifetime: 86400 
Cookie Path: / 
Cookie Domain: Your Domain
Use HTTP Only: YES 
Cookie Restriction Mode: No

Important settings is HTTP Only: YES.